# Change Braintree Placeholder Text Color

Tags: braintree

Is there any way to change the placeholder text color in a Braintree javascript generated hosted field? I don't see it as one of [the options](https://braintree.github.io/braintree-web/3.6.3/module-braintree-web_hosted-fields.html#~styleOptions) you can pass into the constructor. Our design is on a dark background, and the placeholder values aren't visible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

There is a way to change the placeholder color, which isn't documented since it's not a 100% fix.

However, in your JS you could do the following:

```
braintree.hostedFields.create({
  client: clientInstance,
  styles: {
    'input': {
      'font-size': '14pt'
    },
    'input.invalid': {
      'color': 'red'
    },
    'input.valid': {
      'color': 'green'
    },
    '::-webkit-input-placeholder': {
      'color': 'pink'
    },
    ':-moz-placeholder': {
      'color': 'pink'
    },
    '::-moz-placeholder': {
      'color': 'pink'
    },       
    ':-ms-input-placeholder': {
      'color': 'pink'
    },
},
```

This isn't a 100% fix because not all browsers support even adding a placeholder, so when styling the placeholder element, the browser prefixes are needed so that each browser can attempt to render the style you want.  If a customer goes to access this outside of a browser specified, however, it won't be a fix.

Comment: I'd venture to say that this is still worth documenting! Searched for a while in the Braintree documentation, then googled and found this when I couldn't find it there.

Comment: Is this answer still true in 2021?